# How to get state name for the current location using reverse geocode in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

I want to get the current location information of the device. I am able to get the current location info, but the problem is I am getting state name as code like "MN", I am not able to get the full state name. How can I get the state name instead of state code. or
 If you know how to convert state code into state name please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Blackberry Native Reverse geocoding you can't get exact State name because as per my knowledge Blackberry doesnt provide all detail of perticular area.

But you get full State name using Google Map API . [Google Map API URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=23.33445,72.343355&sensor=false)

pass your lat/lng in this url and you will get responce in xml/json . In this responce `administrative_area_level_1` of `type` tag is your State name .

Parse this and get this .
i hope it is use full to you.